# Get and split multiple values from database field and view them as selected in a multiple select listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

```
I want to get the values in a string from a database which i can do and my result is
```

string strValues = "'value1','value2','value3'";
i know we can split them using the split function. But the problem is how to mark them in the list box.

```
    <asp:ListBox ID="lstValues" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">[``Select]</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">value 10</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">value 9</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">value 3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">value 2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="5">value 1</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstValues" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">[``Select]</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">value 10</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">value 9</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">value 3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">value 2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="5">value 1</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:ListBox>

add Selected="true" on the Items you want to be checked! 
Example:  <asp:ListItem Value="5" selected="true">value 1</asp:ListItem>

you can also use Checked="true" for list boxes
```